# Subscript error trying to get values from a class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add up all values from a class together. This is my code:

```
 var allPlayersArray: [allPlayersIngame] = []

class allPlayersIngame {
        let username: String
        let uid: String
        var score: Int

        init(username: String, uid: String, score: Int) {
            self.username = username
            self.uid = uid
            self.score = score
        }
    }

var totalScore = 0
    for playerScore in self.allPlayersArray{
    if let score = self.allPlayersArray[playerScore].score{
    }//error
     totalScore += allPlayersArray[playerScore].score
    }//error
    self.averageScore = totalScore / self.allPlayersArray.count
}
```

The error is as followed:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[vc.allPlayersIngame]' with an index of type 'vc.allPlayersIngame'

My approach was to loop through every array element and get their score. Well this did not work out well.

Comment: Unrelate but please note you should use standard naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase letters. Function and variable names start with lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up *index* based and *item* based `for loop`

It's either (*index* based)

```
for index in 0..<self.allPlayersArray.count {
     totalScore += allPlayersArray[index].score
}
self.averageScore = totalScore / self.allPlayersArray.count
```

or (*item* based)

```
for playerScore in self.allPlayersArray {
     totalScore += playerScore.score
}
self.averageScore = totalScore / self.allPlayersArray.count
```

---

or (*no loop* based)

```
let totalScore = self.allPlayersArray.map({ $0.score }).reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the array. `playerScore` is already each object from the array. You can't then use that object to index the array.

And you can't unwrap a non-optional.

Change your code to:

```
var totalScore = 0
for playerScore in allPlayersArray {
    totalScore += playerScore.score
}
averageScore = totalScore / allPlayersArray.count
```